# Why private mode of safari does not support localstorage setItem?

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage

I am in charge of developing and maintaining several website on client-side. When it comes to temporary storage, I always think about localstorage in the first step. It is a fantastic feature which is introduced from html5 and it help me conquer many tasks for a long time.

However, it doesn't perform so well on private mode of safari browser. Precisely, it will broken when calling `localstorage.setItem(...)`. So every time I use localstorage, I need to do some workaround only for private safari and it is depressing.

I am just curious why private safari does not support it? Is it really a big deal for making such feature compatible with current version? After all, we have a [95.37%](https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) support from modern browser now. (I know merely about the inside of modern browsers so if it sounds stupid please just ignoring it)

I am also looking for alternative solution which support all modern browsers.

Any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: I thought the one purpose of private mode was to be anonymous - you can't well be anonymous with cruft in your localstorage

Comment: I'd go with **localForage**: https://localforage.github.io/localForage/. It should have detection for private mode and switching to alternate storage for it.